# python subprocess provide input and read output multiple times [windows]

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, blocking

I am trying to create a python script which uses subprocess module to connect to database in a database server and do administrative activity on connected database.

This is the sample script which i am trying to

```
from subprocess import Popen , PIPE

p =  Popen(['cmd'], stdin=PIPE ,stdout = PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

p.stdin.write(b'ipconfig\n') # write to stdin
print (p.stdout.read()) # read stdout


p.stdin.write(b'sqlplus sys/sys@orcl as sysdba\n')
print (p.stdout.read())

p.stdin.write(b'shutdown immediate\n')
print (p.stdout.read())

p.stdin.write(b'startup\n')
print (p.stdout.read())
```

After every input i need to check the output to ensure there isn't any error. For any output or error a proper msg needs to be propagated back to the user or the calling program.

The above script gets hanged may be after the first stdout.read thing. I checked various similar questions and articles but none of what i read provided something which works. Please let me know what can i do here.

Comment: The pipes are [file](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) objects.  `.read` with no parameters blocks until end of file is reached. If there is nothing to read, but the process has not closed, your read will hang.

Comment: Not knowing your true goal here, you might take a look at the [pexpect](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/) module, as well.

Comment: I see no reason why you'd do this by writing commands to a CMD shell session. These commands (e.g. "ipconfig.exe") should all be run individually, after which for each you would wait and get the return code via `rc = p.wait()`. A return code of 0 means success, and a non-zero value usually indicates a failure, but this depends on the program.